# How to define a function to be used in a loop?

Tags: function-construction

I have written following piece of codes which is a part of very larger program.

```
x = ConstantArray[0, 7];
i0 = Range[-2, 2]/2;
i1 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {400, 7}];
For[u = 1, u <= 7, u++, x[[u]] = Position[Abs[i1[[300, u]] - i0], Min[Abs[i1[[300, u]] - i0]]]];
```

The question is when I am going to change it in a way to look simpler by defining a function as:

```
index[u_] := Abs[i1[[300, u]] - i0];
```

and the `For` loop like:

```
For[u = 1, u <= 7, u++, x[[u]] = Position[index[u], Min[index[u]]]];
```

I face this error:

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Abs in Abs[{1.,0.5,0.,-0.5,-1.}+{0.498994,2.91363,1.70631,-0.708323,-1.91564,-0.708323,1.70631}][u_] is Protected.

Note that the number "300" has been chosen arbitrarily and it can be any number between "1" and "400" or the `For` command itself can be in an outer loop iterating "1-400".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with clean Kernel before trying the second case loop. Do you still get the error? Or write `ClearAll[x,i0,i1]` before trying again.

Comment: Besides, you might get a slightly faster execution time when changing the `For` loop to `Position[index[#], Min[index[#]]] & /@ Range[7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `Position`, it's faster to just look for the position of the smallest element directly with [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html):

```
i0 = Range[-2, 2]/2;
i1 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {400, 7}];
x = Table[First[Ordering[Abs[i1[[300, u]] - i0], 1]], {u, 7}]
```

Also, `Table` is generally preferred over pre-allocating a list and populating it with `For`.

If you insist on the format of `x` with the nested curly braces, then replace the last line with

```
x = Table[{Ordering[Abs[i1[[300, u]] - i0], 1]}, {u, 7}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting it like this fixes the error:

```
index[start_Integer, u_Integer] := Abs[i1[[start, u]] - i0];
```

Then, your for loop becomes this

```
For[u = 1, u <= 7, u++, x[[u]] = Position[index[300, u], Min[index[300, u]]]];
```

This yields the same result as your initial code and uses a function.

One suggestion, try to avoid "For" loops.  Since you are just iterating over a row, this would do the trick:

```
With[{row = i1[[300]]}, Position[Abs[# - i0], Min[Abs[# - i0]]] & /@ row]
```

It also yields the same result, which is this: 
{{{3}}, {{1}}, {{3}}, {{5}}, {{3}}, {{1}}, {{5}}}